# apt is not working after I changed mirror

Tags: debian, apt

I was trying to install **apt-transport-https** (it was a **tox** dependency) when the mirror I was using (http://ftp3.nrc.ca) shut down.

Then I changed to the mirror http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/, but when I tried to execute `apt-get update` I had this error:

`N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `apt-get` wants to download using HTTP over TLS rather than plain HTTP; check that your `sources.list` doesn't specify `https://`.

If it does, change it, then `apt-get install apt-transport-https` should work. Once you've installed that, change it back to using `https://`.

If it doesn't, the mirror is redirecting you, so you need to fix your setup manually; download the appropriate `.deb` for [`apt-transport-https`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt-transport-https) (probably [this one](http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8_amd64.deb) if you're using Jessie on `amd64`) and install it using

```
dpkg -i apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8_amd64.deb
```

That should allow `apt-get` to download files. You may need to install [`libcurl3-gnutls`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libcurl3-gnutls) in the same way if nothing else installed it.